# How to refresh page after dialog has completed?

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm running a dialog (the workflow-ish one, not a custom, modal window) on *Customer* and during the process, an instance of a related entity *Project* is created. All the related instances of *Project* are displayed in a subgrid on the *Contact* form.

The problem is that the most recently added instance of *Project* isn't view **until a refresh of the page** which confuses the users. How can I force the form to refresh when a dialog has run?

I've googled the issue but the only resolution I've found are to a modal dialog frames à la JavaScript. The abundance of these drowns any relevant hits, as far I can see (if there are any, that is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find refreshing the page after a dialog closes in CRM Online impossible in the way you describe.  As such my only recommendations are to flag up to the user before the dialog closes that they will need to refresh the page or to do something custom via a ribbon button.